# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Простая задача на кодварс, все тесты код проходит, но ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" не пропускает решение. В чем проблема и почему в строке под * `names[names.length - 2].name` - undefiend?

**Условие задачи:**

Given: an array containing hashes of names

Return: a string formatted as a list of names separated by commas except for the last two names, which should be separated by an ampersand.

Example:

```
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
// returns 'Bart, Lisa & Maggie'

list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])
// returns 'Bart & Lisa'

list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])
// returns 'Bart'

list([])
// returns ''
```

**Мое решение:**

```
function list(names){  
    let result = names.map(item => item.name).join(', ').split(' ');
    result[result.length - 2] = names[names.length - 2].name + ' &'; //*
    result = result.join(' ');
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Подумайте про список из одного элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу, конечно, тоже хотелось бы увидеть, но в данном вопросе и так сойдет. На данный момент у вас в result список имен, а не объектов:

```
result = ['Bart,', 'Lisa,', 'Maggie,', 'Homer,', 'Marge']
```

Когда вы получаете строку `"Homer"` и пытаетесь потом сделать `"Homer".name` получаете `undefined` т.к. у строки никакого name нет.

```js
list([{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'},{name: 'Maggie'},{name: 'Homer'},{name: 'Marge'}])
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])
list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])
list([])

function list(names){  
    let result = names.map(item => item.name).join(', ').split(' ');
    result[result.length - 2] = names[names.length - 2] && names[names.length - 2].name + ' &'; //*
    result = result.join(' ');
    console.log(result);
}
```

--- UPD ---

Если вы используете уже map и другие функции массивов, можно взять к себе на вооружение reduce и reduceRight, которые очень помогают в некоторых случаях.

```js
list([{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'},{name: 'Maggie'},{name: 'Homer'},{name: 'Marge'}])
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'}, {name: 'Maggie'} ])
list([ {name: 'Bart'}, {name: 'Lisa'} ])
list([ {name: 'Bart'} ])
list([])


function list(names){  
    let result = names.length === 0 ? '' : names.map(x => x.name).reduceRight((p, c, i, a) => {
        return c + (i === a.length - 2 ? " & "  : ", ") + p;
    })
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Я не очень понимаю на счет строки. Вы написали, что "Homer".name является undefined, но ведь я вызываю "Homer" из массива объектов names.

Comment: Без `.name` в `result[result.length - 2].name`  точно такая же ошибка.

Comment: @At-Sky, да, я посмотрел на undefined с левой стороны, где `result[result.length - 2].name` и отписался об этом. С правой стороны тоже будет ошибка, вы правы, если элементов меньше 2-х. Я поправил ответ. Ошибка из-за того, что вы пытаетесь получить элемент, которого не существует: `names[-1]` если элемент один или `names[-2]` если их 0. И получаете опять же undefined.

Comment: @At-Sky, хотя на современный манер можно написать покороче: `names[names.length - 2]?.name` вместо `names[names.length - 2] && names[names.length - 2].name`. Ссылка на MDN: [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь на одну непонятную проблему меньше.